# Play: Reading a config file in a test

Tags: playframework

In a Play framework application test file there is a method that calls following code:

```
Play.application().classloader().getResourceAsStream(fileName)
```

which is returning stream as null for a fileName referring to a yaml file in the conf folder.

In the FunSuite testcase, I am using FakeApplication()

```
running(FakeApplication()) {
  ...
}
```

Could you please suggest, what can be wrong such that I am getting stream as null.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm guessing by config you mean the variables that you define within your `application.conf`.

So the way I learn to do it is:

1. **Class that has subset of the configuration**: Just to avoid confusion, I create a class, that gets the information from the configuration file.
2. **Inject the class within your test**: Then I use `app.injector` to inject that class within the body of your test class:

   ```
   val appInjector = app.injector 
   val config = injector.instanceOf(classOf[WhateverConfigClass])
   ```